# Itext Pdf VerifyError: Rejecting class

Tags: android, itext, itextg

I'm creating demo for convert "**html content to pdf**" using "**itext**" library.Generating pdf normal way pdf successfully but when i'm adding below option build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

"itextpdf" below compile dependency added-

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
```

Error:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName'

How to reoslve this issue? or give me some pdf library name.

Comment: Is this an error you get from Gradle? Which version of iText are you using? Since you used the Android tag, do you use the Android port, iTextG?

Comment: I m update question and more described in question my project build.gradle file plz check.